# Authenticating registration against two tables: Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.1

I'm new to Laravel and am trying to figure out how to authenticate against two tables during new user registration.

I've modified the default methods in `AuthController` -  I'm checking to see if a store number is valid, and if it is, register the user. This works fine - if the store number provided checks out, the user is inserted into both tables (`user` and `user_store`) and redirected to the dashboard page.

<s>However, if the validation against `$store` is false, then I receive the following error</s>

<s>**Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given**</s>

As you can see in the code I'm just trying to redirect to the `auth/register` view and provide an error message that the store number was invalid. Where am I going wrong?

**SEE UPDATED CODE BELOW THIS BLOCK...**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:user',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'store_number' => 'required',
    ]);
}



protected function create(array $data)
{

    if(!$store = Store::where('number', $data['store_number'])->first()) {

        // HERE'S WHERE I'M HAVING THE PROBLEM

        return redirect('auth/register')->withErrors('store_number','Could not find a match for the Store Number');

    } else {

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        $data['sid'] = $store->id;
        $data['uid'] = $user->id;

        $store = UserStore::create($data);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've since moved this into the `validator()` method, because, well, it makes more sense to do the validation in the `validator()` method... right?

Here's my new code.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    if(!Store::where('number', $data['store_number'])->first()) {
        // still not working!
        return redirect('auth/register')->withErrors('store_number','Could not find a match for the Store Number');
    }

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:user',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'store_number' => 'required',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $s['sid'] = $data['store_number'];
    $s['uid'] = $user->id;

    $store = UserStore::create($s);

    return $user;
}
```

And here's my new error message

**BadMethodCallException in RedirectResponse.php line 198:
Method [fails] does not exist on Redirect.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to use the `After` validation hook inside the `validator()` method. :)

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:user',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'store_number' => 'required',
    ]);

    $validator->after(function($validator) {
        if(!Store::where('number', $_POST['store_number'])->first()) {
            $validator->errors()->add('store_number', 'Could not find a match for the Store number');
        }
    });

    return $validator;
}
```